# Android dropbox upload/download app to an SD card

Tags: java, android, dropbox

I'm trying to make an app that uploads a file to dropbox and downloads it.
Uploading seems to work, downloading doesn't. Also it doesn't actually upload from my SD card but from my phone internal memory.

saveOnDropbox() uploads a file.txt from phone/MyFiles/file.txt to dropbox app folder.

saveOnDevice() - something happens when I use this, but the file doesn't get neither to my phone or SD card

```
public void saveOnDropBox() throws IOException, DropboxException {


    File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File file = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/MyFiles/file.txt"); 
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    DropboxAPI.Entry response = dropboxAPI.putFile("/file.txt", inputStream,
            file.length(), null, null);


    Log.i("D bExam pleLog", "The uploaded file's rev is: " + response.rev);
}





public void saveOnDevice() {

    FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
    try {
        File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

        File file = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/MyFiles/file.txt");
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

        DropboxAPI.DropboxFileInfo info = dropboxAPI.getFile("/file.txt", null, outputStream, null);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Som ething w ent w rong: " + e);
    } finally {
        if (outputStream != null) {
            try {
                outputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("___" + e);
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: You are confusing [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) and [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html). You do not have arbitrary filesystem access to removable storage.